# Using variable in excel RC reference

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA/macro coding.  Trying to insert a variable in RC reference and it is not working.  I am not sure where I am making a mistake, any guidance is appreciated.

```
Dim var1 As Integer
Dim var2 As Integer
var1 = 1  'this changes dynamically in my actual program
var2 = 2  'this changes dynamically in my actual program
Range("A2").Select
'following doesn't work
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[var1]/RC[var2]"
'following works
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]/RC[2]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables don't expand within string literals.  You should explicitly build the string:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[" & CStr(var1) & "]/RC[" &CStr(var2) & "]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using string concatenation (`&`):

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC" & var1 & "/RC" & var2
```